# How to detect MYSQL slow queries when using rackspace Database

Tags: mysql, performance, rackspace, mysql-slow-query-log

Is there any easy way to see the slow queries in Rackspace MySQL?

I tried to follow [their instructions](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/access-slow-query-and-general-logs-for-cloud-databases)

But it is too complicated...

Comment: Rackspace Knowledge Base is nicely written almost all the time, i would suggest you to follow it